# How to determine all the numbers of elements in each set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have these sets defined with the set-builder below:

$ S = \{1,2,.....,100\}$

$ A = \{x\in S:3|x\} $

$ B = \{x\in S:5|x\} $

$ C = \{x\in S:7|x\} $

And now they want the number of elements in the subsets below:

$ A \cap B \cap C $

$ A \cap B \cap C^c $

$ A \cap B^c \cap C $

$ A \cap B^c \cap C^c$

$ A^c \cap B \cap C $

$ A^c \cap B \cap C^c$

$ A^c \cap B^c \cap C$

$ A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c$

The problem is not that i don't know how to do this i can list all elements like
{3,6,9,....,99}
{5,10,15,...,100}
{7,14,21,....,98}

And see what is the common elements in each set and list all the numbers of complements but this will take forever and i'don't know any faster way to this?

And it will take forever to list all the complements elements $A^c,B^c,C^c$ ?
Complement means all elements that are not in A,B,C?

My question is that must i list all elements in each complement and A,B,C or is there any faster way to do this?

Is there i am getting stuck?

Comment: A question to ask yourself is how many numbers $n$ are there less than 100 that are divisible by $d$?  HINT: What does $n/d$ give you? After that, to find no of elements in intersection, think about when $n$ would be divided by both? HINT: What does **lcm** or **gcd** do?

Comment: I am not sure if you know about it yet, but another way after finding number of elements for individual divsiors($n(A), n(B), n(C)$), you could also use the *[principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*

Comment: @Naitik Mundra For 3 it is 33 that is divisible and for 5 it is 20 that is divisible up to 100 and for 7 it is 14 numbers but how can i see which are common in the complement and common in the intersection of each set?

Comment: the complement is the opposite, right. What does that mean in terms of the universal set and the given set? HINT: Total - given set

Comment: read my full comment in the first one, also the second one. It answers the latter part of your question as well

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to know to calculate the number of elements of sets of the form $\{n\in S \backslash d\lvert n\}$ ,where $d$ is some positive integer.
Since $3;5;7$ are mutually coprime, $A\cap B \cap C=\{n\in S \backslash 105\lvert n\}$,In particular $A\cap B \cap C=\emptyset $,in general
$$\{n\in S \backslash a\lvert n\} \cap \{n\in S \backslash b\lvert n\}=\{n\in S \backslash Lcm(a,b)\lvert n\} $$
Edit: After a suggestion by @Naitik Mundra: 
Let's compute the number of elements of the last example: 
$A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c}=(A\cup B \cup C)^{c}$, we know that $\lvert D^{c} \rvert=\lvert S\rvert-\lvert D \rvert$, 
So it suffices to calculate the number of $A\cup B \cup C $, we have (by the inclusion-exclusion principle)  $\lvert(A\cup B \cup C)\rvert=\lvert A\rvert+\lvert B \rvert+\lvert C\rvert-\lvert A\cap B \rvert-\lvert A\cap C \rvert-\lvert B\cap C \rvert+\lvert A\cap B \cap C\rvert$

Comment: I would suggest adding a short blurb on counting number of elements in intersection. (or atleast a link to something like the principle of inclusion-exlusion) for further reading as well.

Comment: @NaitikMundra How can i find the intersection of A and B for example to count for intersection between 3 sets?

Comment: @NaitikMundra Thank you for the suggestion,I edited the post

Comment: @mire12 that needs to be using the lcm mentioned in the original answer. (for A and B, lcm is 15. so find number of elements divisible by 15.)

Comment: @NaitikMundra How do i calculate the lcm to find that many numbers that A and B has common?

Comment: @mire12 LCM is the lowest common multiple. See [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). After that just find out $100/lcm$ to figure out number in two sets intersection.
Remark: I think you need to revise some basic concepts first before doing this. You seem to miss the fundamentals.

Comment: @NaitikMundra Okay i understand the thing with intersection and lcm but how do i find for example the union of A and B and C?

Comment: @mire12 look at the answer here. it is answered clearly. More sepcifcally, the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @NaitikMundra if i divide 100/105 i get 0.95?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140437/discussion-between-naitik-mundra-and-mire12).